# Missing chunk of the side of a laminate countertop

Tags: repair

I just bought a piece of property that included a 49 yo trailer.  Am trying to fix up as best I can.  There is a big chunk missing from the countertop.  I really don't want to replace the countertop and am hoping there is something I can do to patch up the countertop and then I can paint the entire thing.  Anybody know how I can fix??

Comment: We're going to need a picture of the damaged area.

Comment: Get another piece of laminate larger than the the missing chunk, cut the section out and install the new piece. Make sure to sand and fill the lines where the patch is. There are some good counter top paints out there that can make this look good if the patch is done correctly. Depending on the size of the damage and size of the countertop it may be much faster to replace. A photo would be helpful here. Just a note junk fixes make junk property’s look worse, but a creative low cost fix can improve the value.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you want to paint it, autobody filler (Bondo® or similar) or wood putty.

Not a particularly nice fix, but good enough for paint, given that a nice fix is exactly what you don't want to do (replace it, it's 49 years old and broken.)